# Obfuscate (if at all) $_SESSION and $_COOKIE variables?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, obfuscation

Hi folks would really appreciate your help in answering this rather involved question.  Please don't dismiss me on length, I promise it's an easy to comprehend read!

**When and how should you obfuscate (if at all) $_SESSION and $_COOKIE variables** in context to login.php and login_validation.php for the following membership based website?

This membership based website is written in php and uses mysql as its relational database.

### login.php

```
<?php
//Connect to database
$email = $_POST['email'];   //from a text field
$password = $_POST['password']; //from a password field
$password= md5($password);
$stayLoggedIn= $_POST['stayLoggedIn'];  //from a checkbox, value="yes" for checked, value="no" for unchecked

$sql = "SELECT id 
        FROM users
        WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

$query=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row["id"];   
    $encodedID_session= base64_encode("iofj4983rn9dh83$id");
    $_SESSION['id'] =$encodedID_session;

    if($stayLoggedIn== 'yes'){
        $encodedID_cookie=base64_encode("dj02359t5ng842$id");
        setcookie("idCookie", $encodedID_cookie, time()+60*60*24*7, "/");
        setcookie("passwordCookie", $password, time()+60*60*24*7, "/");
    }
 }
?>
```

He has a file called login_validation.php which goes at the top of every single page of the website (except login.php).

### login_validation.php

first it decodes the session and cookie variables if they are set (example for decoding session variable below)

```
$decodedID = base64_decode($_SESSION['id']);
$array = explode("iofj4983rn9dh83", $decodedID);
$id = $array[1];
```

Then it does only one of the following:

- if the session AND cookie are not set it displays the header "You are not logged in"
- if the session is set, it queries mysql to find the name of the person in the same row as
  his or her id and displays the personalized header "You are logged in,
  welcome Bonzo!"
- if the session is not set but the cookies are set (ex. user selected
  stayLoggedIn, shut down his computer, and opened up a fresh browser) it queries mysql to find
  the name of the person in the same row as his or her id and displays
  the personalized header "You are logged in, welcome Bonzo!"

The developer has done a few things which I left me a little confused like obfuscating a session variable, or obfuscating two (instead of one) cookie.  Also his method of obfuscation using base64 seems vulnerable to threat if someone got a hold of his nonsense strings he appends.

**When and how should you obfuscate (if at all) $_SESSION and $_COOKIE variables** in context to login.php and login_validation.php for this membership based website?

Thank you, thank you!

EDIT:  Just to clarify I did not pay anyone for this code, instead I'm trying to learn php and got this code from a php tutorial which looked like it could be improved.

EDIT 2: The password is now hashed before validation

Comment: Why would you ever obfuscate `$_SESSION` values? Unless you think your server is compromised, they're only known to your application; they're stored on your server, not on the client.

Comment: Don't save  the MD5 hash of the password in a cookie.

Comment: Also, have you met [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)? You will be good friends. You  are talking about "the developer", if you paid him for this, get your money back.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why he obfuscates $_SESSION.  However I've only been doing php for a month, so I didn't know what is protocol.  Ty cularis for the tip.  And as for the "developer", It's some guy who posted a youtube tutorial on php and I got the code from his site.  I'm studying it to learn php.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought this was some contractor who coded this for you.

Comment: The password is hashed in the cookie, but stored as plaintext in the database? It should be hashed in the database (and preferably with something better than md5, plus salt) and NOT stored in the cookie.

Comment: Ah, yet another useless PHP tutorial that does more harm than good :(

Comment: Aether, the password someone enters upon signing up is hashed and sent to the database.  The posted password in the login form is not hashed (this is a login form, not a sign up form or a change password form) and afterwards $password is set to the posted password.  It is eventually hashed in the cookie.

Comment: @LedZeppelin Then I don't see how the query will return any results at all, since you are looking for rows where the stored (hashed) password is equal to the posted (unhashed) value. Unless your password is an md5 fixed point ( `x=md5(x)` ), then you won't return a row (or you need to enter your hashed password in the login form).

Comment: Code corrected, my bad gentleman.  I tried to pare down this guy's code because a lot was going on and missed that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to obfuscate anything stored in the `_SESSION` variable. It is not sent to the client, so you can trust it with sensitive information.

I would recommend that you generate and store a unique authentication token for each logged in user. PHP will maintain the session even after a user has logged out (PHP doesn't know about "logging in" and "logging out"), so keep the idCookie and store it's value along with the user id, for example:

```
if ($stayLoggedIn) {
    $token = sha256(generateRandomNumber());
    $_SESSION["token"] = $token;
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $id;
    setcookie("authenticationtoken", $token, ...)
}
```

When you are verifying authentication check that the "authenticationtoken" cookie matches the stored session variable. The authentication token must be random and never re-used. When a user logs out unset the session's "token" and "userid" variables.

The way you have it right now means an attacker can watch the cookies going past over the wire and do a simple reverse md5 lookup (rainbow tables for alphanumeric strings are pretty easy to generate) to obtain a user's password. The attacker can also easily guess other users' session ids.

Remember to use https everywhere to prevent cookie stealing. If you are sending authentication tokens over http then you might as well not bother even checking passwords (think Firesheep).

Also, and this is important, **don't store cleartext passwords in your database**. You should use something like bcrypt (there's a function for it in PHP) for password storage. If an attacker compromises your database then they have obtained **all** your users' passwords. This is A Bad Thing (think Playstation Network).

As important: Make sure you sanitize user input. Don't just pass user input straight to the database. You need to properly escape any special SQL characters, otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Waiting, will take a shower in the mean time.  By the way I read your answer over twice and already got some great insight, so thank you.  Will be back to see what you're changing.

Comment: Good answer. Someone observing "garbage + userid" won't be able to start accurately guessing session IDs if GUIDs are used for userids, but somehow, I get the impression that this is unlikely. There would still be issues of the same user always getting the same session ID.

Comment: Cameron, this isn't storing cleartext passwords in the database.  Read my most recent comment in under my post in response to Aether.

Comment: OK. The original question (before the edit) was doing an SQL select on the submitted password. Still, storing a single MD5 hash of the password is not secure. You should really look at bcrypt, or at least store a salted, iterated hash. See http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html for a good discussion of how to store passwords. The take-home message is that you need a random, per-user salt and a slow hash function. That's right, a **slow** hash function.

Comment: Hi Cameron,  thanks for revisting the question and keeping in touch.  I've spent some time today reading the documentation for phppass (a random, per-user salt, slow has function) http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ and will set it up right now.  I'm going to throw up a bounty on this question too with some sample code of how I'm going set cookies and sessions to clarify if my way incorporates all the suggested improvements so be on the lookout for that.  Thanks again.